# Breaking out of a forM_ (insertion Sort with mutable vectors)

Tags: haskell, insertion-sort

I am writing an insertion sort in Haskell using mutable vectors. I can't figure out how to break out of a `forM_` loop. I have commented where I need to do that.

```
mvInsertionSort :: Ord a => Mv.IOVector a -> IO (Mv.IOVector a)
mvInsertionSort mv = do
    forM_ [1 .. Mv.length mv - 1] $ \x -> do
        pivot <- Mv.read mv x
        forM_ [x-1 , x-2 .. 0] $ \y -> do
            currElem <- Mv.read mv y
            if pivot < currElem then Mv.write mv y pivot >> Mv.write mv (y+1) currElem
                else Mv.write mv (y+1) pivot -- Exit out of the second forM_ loop here
    return mv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can always use a continuation monad to provide extra return points:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
import Data.Vector.Mutable as Mv

    mvInsertionSort :: Ord a => Mv.IOVector a -> IO (Mv.IOVector a)
    mvInsertionSort mv = do
     () <- evalContT $ callCC $ \exit ->
             forM_ [1 .. Mv.length mv - 1] $ \x ->
              do pivot <- Mv.read mv x
                 forM_ [x-1 , x-2 .. 0] $ \y ->
                  do currElem <- Mv.read mv y
                     if pivot < currElem
                         then do Mv.write mv y pivot
                                 Mv.write mv (y+1) currElem
                         else do Mv.write mv (y+1) pivot
                                 exit ()
     return mv
```

But I think most people just write custom recursive definitions instead.

Comment: i am still having some trouble. The monad types are not matching.

Comment: `Expected type: V.MVector
                       (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (ContT () IO)) a
        Actual type: Mv.IOVector a
    • In the first argument of ‘Mv.read’, namely ‘mv’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: pivot <- Mv.read mv x`

Comment: The code I have shown type checks.  It sounds like you probably want to `liftIO` the various `read`, `write`, etc calls in `mvInsertionSort` but I'm not sure.